# подключение log4j к проекту java

Tags: java, log4j

подскажите куда надо поместит xml файл с настройками?
тоже самое и проперти файл?

Comment: как понимать корень проекта?

Comment: если у тебя maven проект то в папку src/main/resources под названием log4j.xml, тоже самое с properties

Answer (score 1):

В корень проекта к примеру.Дело в том что в Log4j есть возможность конфигурировать себя автоматом во время инициализации.Ну а алгоритм поиска [следующий](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html):

> Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and,
>   if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>   ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension. If no system
>   property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for
>   log4j2-test.properties in the classpath. If no such file is found the
>   YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or
>   log4j2-test.yml in the classpath. If no such file is found the JSON
>   ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn
>   in the classpath. If no such file is found the XML
>   ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.
>   If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory
>   will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath. If a properties file
>   cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for
>   log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the classpath. If a YAML file cannot be
>   located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or
>   log4j2.jsn on the classpath. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML
>   ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.
>   If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration
>   will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.